# How do you create logic in an jQuery animation callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pause

I am trying to build an asynchronous application with jQuery. I have recently learned some of the concepts of how a setInterval can make constant calls to a function and the logic in other function protect the activity when not ready for it. The code I show is just a rough draft of what I want to do, not a working copy. My problem is I cannot seem to create logic that pauses one part of an animation indefinitely and then resumes (when ready) the rest of it. I guess I am asking how do you create logic in an animation callback function? Thanks

```
var runAnimation;
var timePassed;
var someThing;

$(document).ready(function(){
    asyncFunction();

});

function asyncFunction() {
    if ( someCondition == true ) {
        animationFunction(){

        }
    }
    runAnimation = setInterval(animationConditions, 100)
}

function animationConditions(){
    if ( timePassed = 30 ) {
        if(  someThing == true ) {
            animationFunction() {
        }
    }
    timePassed += 1;
}

function animationFunction() {
    $('#show div')
    .animate({left: 500},1500)
    .delay(3000)
    .queue(function(){  
        someThing = false;
        //but in this section I would like something like a mouseover or
        //other things to be able to pause the animation. I was experimenting
        //with queue and dequeue but any time I use dequeue in this section
        //it turns of the queue, even if the statement fails. For exmaple if it
        //is in an else and the if is true. I would like to be able to add more
        //pause on an event like a mouseover. When mouse leaves resume the animation.

        //if(something == true){
        //  pause aniamtion indefinitely;
        //}


    }).dequeue().animate({left: 1100},1500);    


}
```

While trying to figure it out I came up with this

```
    function animatePause(query, duration, distance){

        checkAp = setInterval(function(){
        if( marqueeVars.autoPlay == false ) {
            console.log("that's one");
            query.delay(70000000000000000).animate({left: distance},function(){
                clearInterval(checkAp);
                console.log("long wait!");
            });
        } else {
            console.log("that's two");
            //console.log(query.html());
            //clearInterval(checkAp);
            query.delay(duration).animate({left: distance},function(){
                clearInterval(checkAp);
                console.log("regular wait!");
                animateOut(query,1100);
            });         
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

I don't understand why the code inside the if() does not execute? It never clears the interval, it never runs the animation? It just seems to be ignored. I think I should understand this concept even thought I am going to look at the plugin. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Greensock Timeline max will do the needful. you can pause, continue, reverse, increase the speed etc using it.

[sample code](https://greensock.com/timelinemax)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are aware of [TweenMax](https://greensock.com/tweenmax) and [TimelineMax](https://greensock.com/timelinemax), but it looks as a better solution for what you are trying to do.

You can create your animation, play it and pause it any time you want.

I rewritten your code. Just remember to add TweenMax and TimelineMax scripts before the following one:

```
// Setup
var element = '#show div',
    duration = 1.5;

// This is your timeline, you can add as many animation as you want
var animation = new TimelineMax();
    animation.add( TweenMax.to( element, duration, { left: 500 } ) );
    animation.add( TweenMax.to( element, duration, { left: 1100, delay: 3 } ) );
    animation.repeat( -1 ); // repeat indefinitely
    animation.repeatDelay( 3 ); // add a delay of 3s before every repetition


// This binds your mouseenter and mouseleave to the animation
$('#show div').hover(
    function() {
        animation.pause();
    }, function() {
        animation.resume();
    });

// You can add some other conditions
if ( someCondition ) {
    animation.pause()
} 
else {
    animation.resume() // you can restart using animation.play() if you prefer 
}

// And finally add it to your document
$(document).ready(function(){
    animation.play();
});
```

PS: I haven't test it on a browser, but it gives you an idea of what the code should look like.

Comment: Wow that is second time that was mentioned, I am going to check out eh GreenSock pulgin. Thanks

Comment: While trying to find a way I came up with this:

Comment: I think you missed to add the link to your comment... Anyway, let me konw how it goes. It's very simple to understand